# Picking certain strings of an array with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to pick paticular strings in an array and add them to a new array e.g. I want to grab all strings in the array that contain .txt and .rtf and add them to a new array e.g. filteredStrings[]

Comment: Do you HAVE to use regex? Would be much simpler to simply use String.Contains

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need regex for something that simple: `Contains` works faster, and is easier to understand:

```
var filteredStrings = myStrings.Where(s => s.Contains(".txt") || s.Contains(".rtf")).ToArray();
```

If you insist on using regex, you can do this:

```
var regexp = new Regex("[.](txt|rtf)");
var filteredStrings = myStrings.Where(s => regexp.IsMatch(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: however regex could be more flexible

Comment: A plugin system would be more flexible; until you need that flexibility don't introduce the burden.

Comment: Since they seem to be file extensions it might be a good idea to use the String.EndsWith() method.

Comment: @Till absolutely, if the OP is indeed talking about file extensions (which I am 99% certain that he does) then `EndsWith` is a preferred choice.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found –

Comment: @Mike You need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"\.(txt|rtf)$")).ToArray()
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found

Comment: @Mike What version of .Net are you using? If 3.5 or later you just need to add Using System.Linq to you file.  If older, then is it possible for you to update to 3.5 or higher?